# How to perform an sql query which joins another table for it's count() column in sequelizejs

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

Here is a raw sql query, I wonder how to perform it in sequelizejs

```
SELECT users.id, count(companies.area)
FROM users
LEFT JOIN companies
ON users.id = companies.user_id
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
User.findAll({
  attributes: ['id', sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('companies.area'))],
  include: [Company]
});
```